# Updated GCM Server-side implementation

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

Last weeks I've been reading the GCM documentation to make my Downstream server-side implementation. 
So I noticed that must be smarter if I use the Google implementation for this, and after a little "googling" I came to  the Google GCM GitHub repository.

The "server-gcm" at this repository seems to be outdated since some parameters like *priority* and *content_available* are not present, but they are referenced at Table 1 of Downstream server reference at GCM documentation. Besides that I can't find the Notification payload at [Message.java](https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/master/client-libraries/java/rest-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/server/Message.java).

So, I have two questions:

1- Does anyone could confirm that [this](https://github.com/google/gcm) is, in fact, the latest version of Google GCM implementation?
2- Does anyone know some updated GCM Java server-side implementation avaiable at GitHub or Bitbucket?

Thanks,

Comment: Here's an issue reported for priority: https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/88.

Comment: Also, the best place to report issue with the sample would be there. And about GCM Java server-side implementation. You could just search online and you will find plenty of tutorials. It is basically not advised to ask for tutorials here.

Comment: @KayAnn, Thanks for your reply, but I think I can't explain my needs. The problem isn't only in priority field, the problem is the hole new structure of GCM that is not present on the repository.
And I'm not asking for a tutorial, I'm not asking for a "how to", I'm only asking If anyone could confirm if the Google GCM repository is realy outdated and if anyone knows a good Java server-side implementation of that. If the answer is NO, ok, I'll make it and make public on GitHub.
For yout information I already find some implementations, but even so I'll make it too.
Thanks for your time.